# Socialengine group-invite doesn't work

Tags: socialengine

I'm developing an application with Socialengine software, and using the Socialengine groups plugin. When I try to invite a user to a group, everything seems to be done OK, but I don't get any invitation at all, and don't even get any activity.
I've been searching and can't find any similar trouble. I can't believe I'm the only one having this problem.
Does anyone had this problem anytime?
Thank you and have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0):

[Socialengine group-invite doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472891/socialengine-group-invite-doesnt-work)

MemberController.php

```
/application/modules/Group/controllers/MemberController.php
```

this is the actual code:

```
$count = 0;
$multiOptions = array();
foreach( $friends as $friend )
{
  if( $group->membership()->isMember($friend, null) ) continue;
  $multiOptions[$friend->getIdentity()] = $friend->getTitle();
  $count++;
}
sort($multiOptions);
$form->users->addMultiOptions($multiOptions);
$this->view->count = $count;
```

this will be the best option to use:

```
$count = 0;
$multiOptions = array();
foreach( $friends as $friend )
{
  if( $group->membership()->isMember($friend, null) ) continue;
  $multiOptions[$friend->getIdentity()] = $friend->getTitle();
  $count++;
}
asort($multiOptions);
$form->users->addMultiOptions($multiOptions);
$this->view->count = $count;
```

or you should use this code too:

```
$count = 0;
foreach( $friends as $friend )
{
  if( $group->membership()->isMember($friend, null) ) continue;
  $form->users->addMultiOption($friend->getIdentity(), $friend->getTitle());
  $count++;
}
$this->view->count = $count;
```